# Open another Popup window within a popup window?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have these two codes. "win2" is what I open first, then when I'm trying to open "win". It doesn't do anything. Please tell me what is wrong

```
    var win;
    function viewTicketDetails() {
        win = window.open('ViewTicketDetailsPage.aspx'
                                , 'TicketDetails'
                                , 'width=1040, height=600, innerHeight=600, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, scrollbars=yes, left=0'
                                , '_blank'); 
       win.focus();
    };


    var win2;
    function viewTicketHistory() {
        win2 = window.open('AffectedUserHistoryPage.aspx'
                                , 'Ticket History'
                                , 'width=1040, height=300, innerHeight=300, location=no, menubar=no, status=no, titlebar=no, scrollbars=yes, left=0'
                                , '_blank');
        win2.focus();
    };
```

Comment: Do you want to open both windows from same page ?

Comment: Yes. Open a pop up window from a window.

Comment: Do you want to open win from win2 ?

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: Google Chrome. Yes exactly!

Comment: I have copy pasted your code and it is working as expected.

Comment: really? I've tried it both in Google Chrome and IE. it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68710/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-user1954418).

Comment: win is a pop up window. win2 is also a pop up window. So, I want to open a new pop up window from a pop up window. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write viewTicketsDetaisl() in the page from where you want to open the second window.
`viewTicketDetails` should be written in `AffectedUserHistoryPage.aspx`.